# When migrating to expatriates, can you check that the question has not already been asked there?

Tags: discussion, expat-questions

Scott here. I am one of the moderators of expatriates.SE, and I have seen twice recently that a question has been asked in expats.SE and also in travel.SE by the same person at around the same time, and then someone migrates the one in travel.SE to expats.SE, so we have the same question asked twice.

Could you please check whether the question already exists in expats.SE before migrating the one in travel.SE? It would be much appreciated by us :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that.
I used to check and will do it again.

Comment: Thank you very much - it is appreciated. We recently had two questions that made it through, and we had to close them

Comment: Keep in mind that moderators are exempt from the system's checks that ordinarily prevent cross-posts from being migrated, and as such are expected to check themselves. This exemption exists for special cases where the checks are to be bypassed intentionally.